# Wordpress без ЧПУ. Как сделать корректный 404-й ответ?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache2, чпу

Добрый день! Есть сайт на Wordpress 4.6.1, terraoko.com. (Веб-сервер — Апач 2.4, на морде стоит nginx, но 404-е обрабатываются Апачем по настройкам). Включить «pretty permalinks» (ЧПУ) нельзя по условиям работы, ссылки "не-человечные". Это вызывает следующую проблему:

Не работает 404-я страница и не возвращается в нужных ситуациях код 404, при обращении на несуществующие URL или файлы отдаётся цепочка кодов 301->200, с дописыванием слэша к URL в адресной строке браузера и визуальному переходу на главную страницу, вот например:
terraoko.com/non-exist-url трансформируется в terraoko.com/non-exist-url

Директива «ErrorDocument 404 /404.html» в .htaccess не помогает (видимо от того что всё что угодно идёт на index.php), а файл 404.php темы при выключенных ЧПУ ссылках тоже не хочет работать (хотя работает при включенных, но включать их не разрешается).

Модуль mod_rewrite включен, опция AllowOverride All для папки сайта тоже.

Можно ли как-то здесь выкрутится (и насколько это реально без включения ЧПУ)?

PS. Заранее признателен!

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!

Попробуйте в index.php добавить условие:

```
if(is_404())
{
    get_template_part('404');
}
```

[is_404()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/is_404) - описание

[get_template_part()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part) - описание

Не забудьте, файл **404.php** должен быть в шаблоне темы.

Comment: В index.php темы не срабатывает, в какое место ни засовывай. В общий index.php ядра WP тоже бесполезно пихать. Как дописывал слэш к несуществующим URL и отображал главную, так и делает. Причем это творится где-то внутри WP всё-таки, т.к. при нарушении его работы через удаление wp-blog-header.php редиректорное безобразие прекращается - и ни в .htaccess, ни в конфиге Апача никаких таких редиректов нету.

Comment: А вот когда из .htaccess полностью удаляешь код, обеспечивающий пермалинки в норме - то всё начинает работать)))

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Но не знаю, насколько это корректно делать так (даже пусть ЧПУ и не используются)...

Answer (score 0):

Так если вы не используете ЧПУ на сайте, то и все реврайты НЕ нужны!  Удалите их, оставив только ErrorDocument